# How can I convert microseconds to H:MM:SS.mmmmmm in DB2/z

Tags: time, db2, mainframe

Using DB2 on the mainframe, I have a value indicating number of microseconds that a job took, say `26,366,861,945`.

Is there any easy way to get that into the `H:MM:SS.mmmmmm` format using standard DB2 functions? In other words, that value above would become `7:19:26.861945`.

If necessary, we can drop the microseconds and accept `HH:MM:SS`.

If it's over 24 hours, I'm not fussed about showing days, `27:02:14` would be fine.

I though about selecting the zero time `plus xx microseconds` but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: How about working out each unit of time and concatenating the values together? It won't look pretty though...

Comment: Agreed, not pretty: You're up against a couple of different issues here: 1. The Time type can't have a duration other than hour, minute, or second added to it.
 2. The Time type doesn't allow values greater than 24 for hours  
        (Incidently, this is indicating that the Time type is for _instants_, not _durations_).  Do you want this as a string, or what?  Why not just leave it as a duration, and translate it on display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's absolutely atrocious, but this should work:

```
WITH

ORIG (TS) AS (
    SELECT BIGINT(REPLACE('26,366,861,945', ',', ''))
    FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
),

CONV (TS) AS (
    SELECT TIMESTAMP_ISO('0001-01-01') + (SELECT TS FROM ORIG) MICROSECOND
    FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
),

FMT (TS) AS (
    SELECT VARCHAR_FORMAT(TS, 'DD-HH24:MI:SS.FF')
    FROM CONV
),

DAYLOC (D) AS (
    SELECT LOCATE('-', TS)-1
    FROM FMT
),

HOURLOC (H) AS (
    SELECT LOCATE(':', TS, (SELECT D FROM DAYLOC))-1
    FROM FMT
),

DY (D) AS (
    SELECT CAST(SUBSTR(TS, 1, LOCATE('-', TS)-1) AS INTEGER)-1
    FROM FMT
),

HOURS (H) AS (
    SELECT CAST(SUBSTR(TS, (SELECT D FROM DAYLOC)+2, 2) AS INTEGER)
    FROM FMT
)

SELECT 
    RTRIM(CHAR(((SELECT D FROM DY) * 24) + (SELECT H FROM HOURS))) ||
    SUBSTR(TS, (SELECT H FROM HOURLOC) +1)
FROM FMT
```

I split it into parts, so it should be fairly easy to follow. Convert the string to an integer, add that to a specific date (the date really doesn't matter, as long as it's the first of the month), then use some string searching / formatting to convert it to hours instead of days.

Comment: You're right, that is atrocious. But it won't be the most atrocious thing in our code base :-) I'll give it a shot Monday morning to see how it goes (I don't have a mainframe at home).

Comment: What? Who doesn't keep a spare mainframe hanging around their home? `:)` I tested this on my z/OS DB2 (v9.1). Obviously, this won't work if your job lasts longer than 31 straight days (although, I also don't think `BIGINT` would hold that many microseconds).

Comment: I am shaking my head so vigorously at this code, but I recognize the genius behind it. Bravo, paxdiablo, bravo! And you never know, maybe someone running Hercules on the sly at home could test this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (I can not test this):

```
TIMESTAMP_ISO('0000-00-00-00:00:00.000000') + MICROSECOND(DB2_TABLE.DB2_COLUMN)
```

Time calculations [DB2 Basics: Fun with Dates and Times](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0211yip/0211yip3.html)
Timestamp function [TIMESTAMP_ISO](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0000826.htm)

Comment: That doesn't work, DB2 says `ERROR [22007] [IBM][DB2] SQL0180N  The syntax of the string representation of a datetime value is incorrect.  SQLSTATE=22007`. Also, I don't think that the `TIMESTAMP_ISO` function would work as you intend. If you only give a time, then it will automatically set the date part as `CURRENT DATE`.

Comment: I forgot that timestamp has date information, try again with the updated query. I'm not sure if date 0000-00-00 is allowed, if not, put your DB2 table low date value like 1900-01-01 and ignore the date part.